# Force the creation and "looping" of single element arrays? (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, variables

I hope to find a compressed solution to array handling over having to duplicate large sections of code only to handle lists of 1 element. (0 element is not a big problem because that needs no execution)

If I create

```
testRange As Variant 
testRange = .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value2 'Case only 1 row in list
IsArray(testRange) 'FALSE!
```

I have tried

```
testRange() As Variant
testRange() As String
...
```

Is there a way to force VBA to create Array also if only 1 elements are fed?
After that is there a way to error-free use either:

```
For i = LBound(testRange) To UBound(testRange)
```

Or

```
For each i in testRange
```

With that 1 member Array, without writing a specific exception only for the sake of 1 member lists?

If none i might return to "good old" method:

```
For each cell in .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
```

The only drawback to this is a bit slower execution, right?

---

**EDIT:**
Nice ideas from @CallumDA
I need some more hints to understand this better, and make it work.
I have tested with:

```
Public Sub Test2()
    Dim testRange As Variant
    With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        testRange = IIf(.Count = 1, Array(.Value2), .Value2)
    End With
    For i = (LBound(testRange)) To (UBound(testRange))
        Debug.Print i & " : " ' & testRange(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Why is it so that when there is 1 element, **i** starts with 0,
BUT when there are multiple elements, **i** starts with 1 ?

Also why is it so, that **testRange(i, 1)** gives a "Suscript out of range" error? (in case of the 1 element scenario)
How should I test the values, that is accepted in both cases?

---

Sidenote: I have made a performance comparison between this array approach and the "each elements" approach to see if it is worth the effort at all.
In case of a 3000 element table list the difference was 2ms vs. 10ms
(So it really is a big difference in terms of multiplier, but luckily also the slower is fast enough for my scenario.)

```
For i = (LBound(testRange)) To (UBound(testRange))
         If testRange(i, 1) = "kaslkfjghh" Then 
VS.
For Each cell In Sheet1.ListObjects(2).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
         If cell.Value2 = "kaslkfjghh" Then
```

Comment: Why is the lower bound for a 2D array pulled from a worksheet Range 1 and not 0?  That's just how it works, likely so you can map the array to the range more easily (since there are no zero-position elements in a Range object)  Note also - if you pick up an array from a (multi-cell) Range it will always be a 2-D array (1 to #rows, 1 to #columns)  If you want a uniform behavior across single- and multi-cell ranges then for a single cell you'd need first to dimension an array (1 to 1, 1 to 1) and then populate it like `arr(1,1) = theCellValue`

Comment: ok, so how to make this work? - I have tried both : `testRange = IIf(.Count = 1, Array(Array(.Value2), Array("1")), .Value2)`  and  `testRange = IIf(.Count = 1, [{.Value2;1}], .Value2)`    But they still gave error with `testRange(i, 1)` in the For loop.  How should i store it to be edible by (i,1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array` to force the element into an array. If there's only ever one element in your `ListColumn` then use this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim testRange As Variant
    testRange = Array(Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value2)
    Debug.Print IsArray(testRange)
End Sub
```

If you sometimes have more than one in your `ListColumn` then use something like this instead:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim testRange As Variant
    With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        testRange = IIf(.Count = 1, Array(.Value2), .Value2)
    End With
    Debug.Print IsArray(testRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested your ideas and came up with a few important questions, please take a look at them. (Under EDIT: )